# Issue with creating POST request ios

Tags: ios, http-post, nsurlrequest

I create a dictionary with fields "email" and "password" and use these params as the body of my request. I get the response from my server that I am missing the parameters email and password - I am positive this is not an issue on the server side. This is how I'm forming the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSString *urlString = @"xxxxxx.xxxx.com/userServices/login";
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : email, @"password" : password};
NSData *bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:45];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Any idea why server would not be recognizing my params?

Answer (score 1):

when creating your dictionary, I would do this

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email] forKey:@"email"];
[params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", password] forKey:@"password"];
```

after that I would do this

```
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil];
```

You might need to give your request a content length

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. I think my dictionary is being formed fine, values show up as intended in the debugger.

Comment: I edited my answer, the difference would be 0 options when packaging the data instead of what you have. The 0 options works for me when I send requests

Comment: Tried 0 options, no difference.

Comment: @dMurdZ what are the params you are expecting at server side?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",[txtUserEmail text],[txtUserPassword text]];
           // what ever in you case e.g [txtuseremail text] replaced by email

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/abc.php"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];


            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

try this may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you:

NSDictionary * requestDict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"email",@"YourEmail",@"password",@"YourPassword", nil];

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request =[[ NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];

NSData * postData =[ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDict options:0 error:nil];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:request
 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                     NSData *data,
                     NSError *error)
 {

     if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
     {

         NSDictionary * dictServerResponse =[ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

         NSLog(@"data %@",dictServerResponse);
         // DO YOUR WORK HERE

     }
     else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
     }
     else if (error != nil){
         NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
     }

 }];
```